# typeid / type_info strange behaviour

Tags: c++, typeid

Why following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
void fun(const T& param)
{
        std::cout << "T = " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "param = " << typeid(param).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << (typeid(T)==typeid(param)) << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
        fun(1);
}
```

gives following output:

```
T is i
param is i
1
```

I know that `type_info::name()` behaviour is implementation dependent. Anyway I would expect `operator==` to return `false` (because `param` is a const reference and not an integer).

Comment: In your code you use `==` but in your question `!=`.  Clarify.

Comment: `typeid` ignores top-level qualifiers (including references).

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: Are you expecting output `int`? If so, [fine print](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid): `filter through c++filt -t if using gcc or similar.`

Comment: I should be more precise: `typeid` can be applied to either a type or an expression (just like `sizeof`). The expression `param` is of type `const T` (remember, expressions are values, never references). And `typeid` ignores the top-level cv-qualifiers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is defined so in the standard:

> **5.2.8/5:** If the type of the expression or type-id is a cv-qualified type, the result of the typeid expression refers to a
>   std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified type  [Example:
>
> ```
> class D { /* ... */ };
> D d1;
> const D d2;
> typeid(d1) == typeid(d2); // yields true
> typeid(D) == typeid(const D); // yields true
> typeid(D) == typeid(d2); // yields true
> typeid(D) == typeid(const D&); // yields true
> ```
>
> —end example ]